# How can I with Linux easily create a collage of passport photos?

Tags: linux, gimp, photos, graphicsmagick

I can easily crop a photo to the right dimensions or [use an online tool](https://www.persofoto.com/upload/passport-photo/html5/437), but I need to make it into a 4x6 because [CVS charges $0.25 for a 4'' x 6''](https://www.cvs.com/photo/prints) but they charge [$12.99 with a coupon for a 2'' x 2''](https://www.cvs.com/photo/prints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `montage`, from graphicsmagisk,

```
apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
```

Then you can simply supply the same file name multiple times followed by the geometry.

```
montage cropped.jpg cropped.jpg cropped.jpg cropped.jpg cropped.jpg cropped.jpg -geometry +2+3 out.jpg
```

Comment: This worked great for tiling a square image. I had to increase the [imagemagick policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699200/4651668) first.